# Lumen with components or laravel

Tags: performance, laravel, frameworks, laravel-5, lumen

I'm currently developing a web application and I expect a lot of visitors (potential thousands of concurrent visitors). For this reason I prefer the Lumen Framework over Laravel because of the size and better performance. But I miss some things that are excluded from Lumen since the last version, like sessions, views and session authentication.

So I have a choice: using the heavier Laravel framework, or use Lumen and add some Laravel components I need. My question is: what is better?

I know I can test some things on my own but I'm not that experienced and I'm wondering if anyone has some good pros or cons (or if you have another alternative I'm curious too).

Comment: If you need most of the components from Laravel, I would prefer to use Laravel. You can optimize your codes well, use caching and load balancing to tackle the potential concurrent visitors.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use Laravel for your purpose. Lumen 5.2 doesn't have views, sessions and can be a bit frustrating create a big website. And since the new version, not her philosophy. Lumen is now focused on JSON API's.

> **Only Stateless APIs**
>
> Lumen 5.2 represents a shift on slimming Lumen to focus solely on serving stateless, JSON APIs. As such, sessions and views are no longer included with the framework.
> If you need access to these features, you should use the full Laravel framework.

https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/releases#5.2.0

If you need an API, is the perfect place to use Lumen. Share the database with the Laravel app (that will contains all the business logic) and you will have a fast API